# PHP in CSS File Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, fatal-error

I am learning wordpress theme development. I want to change some styles in my theme option page. here is the css code

```
background: #<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('header_bg') ); ?>;
```

Theme option page

```
register_setting('theme-setting-group','header_bg');
```

CSS file location : E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\theme-file\css\style.php
Theme option file: E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\theme-file\functions.php

I also added this in my css php file

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css", true);?>
```

when I put those css style in header.php it works fine. But in css php file it is showing this

**Fatal error**:  Call to undefined function esc_attr() in **E:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\theme-file\css\style.php** on line **28**

Answer (score 3):

Your file doesn't exist within the WordPress framework, and as such the WordPress functions like `esc_attr` and `get_option` are unavailable.

You can load in the WordPress framework like so at the top of your `style.php` file:

```
<?php

define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
include('path/to/wp-load.php');
```

Comment: @FaisalAhmed I dunno, does it work? I said to include `wp-load.php`.